# Setting up an authorized connection between a php webservice and a C# WCF client

Tags: c#, php, wcf, soap

Our php webservice provides webfunctions for clients. We have used the following code to do the authentication.

```
$client = new SoapClient("some.wsdl", 
                         array('login' => "some_name",
                               'password' => "some_password"
                         ));
```

The client has been build in C# and we have been able to set up a connection without authentication but we haven't been able to apply the authentication.

what kind of properties should we provide for the clients?
I have tried this configuration in combination with the username credentials.

```
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="webserviceControllerBinding">
                <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
```

client.ClientCredentials .UserName.UserName = "username";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";

What kind of security is our php service using?
How can we set-up a reliable connection with authentication but without using certificates or https.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
   <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
</security>
```

UPDATED: It should be TransportWithMessageCredential mode

Comment: I am getting the following error message 'BasicHttp binding requires that BasicHttpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType be equivalent to the BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate credential type for secure messages. Select Transport or TransportWithMessageCredential security for UserName credentials.' And i don't want to use certificates

Answer (score 0):

It seems I have to put the authentication in the soapheader. 
http://ericphan.info/blog/2010/6/3/adding-custom-http-header-to-all-wcf-requests.html 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/c96c8f6e-0711-4ba1-a97c-008f44610f0e/ 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/SOAPHeaderAuthentication.aspx 
Going by some of the examples on the internet. 
But i haven't found a example for my case jet.

Comment: I had to use http://wcfextras.codeplex.com/ in order to authenticate php client to wcf service (as far as I see your case is other way roumd)

Answer (score 0):

```
         MessageHeader header= MessageHeader.CreateHeader("My-CustomHeader","http://myurl","Custom Header.");

           using (phptoebiTestclient.ServiceReference1.webserviceControllerPortTypeClient client = new phptoebiTestclient.ServiceReference1.webserviceControllerPortTypeClient())
           {
               using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
               {
                   OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(header);
                   HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
                   byte[] toEncodeAsBytes    = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password");                       
                   httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add("Authorization: Basic "+ System.Convert.ToBase64String(toEncodeAsBytes));                                              
                   OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequestProperty;
                   string str = client.getVacanciesReference("");
               }                                 
           }
```

Code above has solved my problem (I used these URLs for reference)

http://caught-in-a-web.blogspot.com/2008/04/how-to-add-custom-http-header-in-wcf.html 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication